# Set Grails Port when Running with Gradle

Tags: grails, gradle

I had a tough time to set the port of a Grails project to something other than 8080. The project was set up with Gradle. I tried all the ways I can think of and found on Google but it does not work. The methods I tried include

```
./gradlew run -PgrailsArgs="-Dgrails.server.port.http=9090"
./gradlew run-app -PgrailsArgs="-Dgrails.server.port.http=9090"
./gradlew grails-run-app -PgrailsArgs="-Dgrails.server.port.http=9090"
./gradlew run -Dgrails.server.port.http=9090
./gradlew -Dgrails.server.port.http=9090 run
./gradlew grails-run-app -PgrailsArgs="--port=9090"
```

as well as out the `grails.server.port.http` property in `build.properties`, `Config.groovy` and `build.grade`. None works. It is hard.

Probably `grail run-app` may work with one of the above option (also using `BuildConfig.groovy`). But "grails run-app" always resulted a resolving error for `org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.5`. I don't see how to get around this way either.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am assuming that it's grails 3.x build.

Answer (score 8):

You can also set port like this

```
-Dgrails.server.port=9090
```

when you start server using Gradle. It works for me

Answer (score 4):

You are using incorrect property name I guess i.e. `grails.server.port.http`. It should be `server.port`.Hence try `... -Dserver.port=8256` etc.

Also, you could specify it in your build.gradle task which you are using to run your application as below. For example you are doing it for springboot application using gradle bootRun.(I actually don't have much working experience in grails 3.0 but have in springboot)

```
bootRun {
   systemProperty 'server.port', '8086'
}
```

This will run your application on 8086 port.

In general, you could try

> gradle your_task_to_run_app -Dserver.port=your_port

Also, if you have application.yml in grails 3 app(as grails 3 uses gradle and springboot.If not present you should be able to create one) then do it like below:

```
app:
 name:Springboot+Config+Yml+Demo
 version:1.0.0
settings:
 counter:1
---
spring:
 profiles:development
server:
 port: 9001
security:
 user.name: 'default'
 user.password: 'default'
```

Let me know it works or not as haven't tried but pretty sure that it will work.

**Edit**: More [this](http://%20nixmash.com/java/setting-the-tomcat-http-port-in-gradle) should help!
Hope it helps!

Comment: hey! found a good link that should definitely help you out http://nixmash.com/java/setting-the-tomcat-http-port-in-gradle/

Comment: Vinay, thanks much for the help. Neither way seems to work. `Dserver.port=8086` is not picked up and the server still running on port 8080. I tried to add either `bootRun` or `run` task into build.gradle ended up an error message like `Could not find method run()...`

Comment: in build.gradle in run task did you try to set env properties like run{addResources = false
systemProperty 'server.port', '8086'}

Comment: It turned out that add `grails.server.port.http = 9090` in `grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy` did the trick. The gradle plugin for grails docs state that `BuildConfig.groovy` is no longer consulted for repository or dependency information, but the file is obviously still consulted for runtime configurations.